# Converting Event Tracking code from Jquery to Mootools

Tags: jquery, joomla, mootools, analytics

I'm working on a Joomla website so it's using Mootools.

I need to use Analytics Event Tracking on the contact form submit button; however, JQuery isn't working and I have tried all of my options by using NoConflict and what not.

This is the Jquery code that I need to use on the submit button. How can I convert it to Mootools?

```
onclick="var _this=this;_gaq.push([
  '_set',
  'hitCallback',
  function( { 
    $(_this).parents('form').first().submit();
  }
]);

_gaq.push([
  '_trackEvent', 
  'Contact', 
  'Appointment',
  ,
  , 
  false]
);

return !window._gat;"
```

Hope you can help.

Thank You.

Comment: and did you try after setting jQuery in noconflict mode to replace `$` with `jQuery`?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I did. The gaq.push was not firing. Is it supposed to work? The main problem that I had was that the form was submitting before firing the Event so I had to add the Jquery code above. Maybe we can fix the root problem?

Comment: what version of MooTools are you using? and are you preventing the default action (submit) on the click? (otherwise the form will submit before the javascript can work)

Comment: Version 1.11. The Joomla website is pretty old. How can I prevent the submit action? I thought the script above prevented it until the Event has been sent.

Answer (score 0):

MooTools 1.1 doesn't support `getParent` with selectors so you might as well use the DOM API directly. I'd rewrite the function (there was a closing paren missing in the code you posted, BTW)

```
function() { 
    $(_this).parents('form').first().submit();
}
```

as follows:

```
function() {
    for (var el = _this.parentNode; el; el = el.parentNode) {
        if (el.tagName == 'form') {
            el.submit();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

If the element to which you add the click handler is an `input` element, you can simply use:

```
function() { _this.form.submit(); }
```

Also note that using the `onclick` attribute is usually bad practice. You should consider adding an event handler using MooTools' `Element.addEvent`.